# Filtering Contact's child custom object data based on its relationship with Contact's Account

Tags: master-detail, lookup-filter

My apologies if this question is answered here earlier...but the ones that I read (case/account/contact filtering etc.) seem different then this.

I have the following relationships...
Account >-< Program >-< Solution

So, Program serves as a junction object that maintains the programs that an Account has brought (Master:Detail) and a Lookup to solutions.

Now I need to allow my Sales rep to associate a contact with one or more program (that the Contact's Account has purchased).

So, I created another junction object called Program membership which has master detail relationship between Contact and Program. This works and I can associate the Contact and Program by creating new records in this object.

However, I am unable to filter the program list to only show programs associated with the Contact's Account.

When I try to use the look up filter on the "Program" field, I do get Program->Account->Account Id but no Program_Membership->Contact->Account Id to compare, so I am unable to filter it.

[image: Contact only appears as a field, not as an object]

I would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!